# flutter: Make page navigation gesture coexist with custom gestures

Tags: flutter, dart, gesture

I'd like to use `PageView` routes and the swipe gesture to implement page switch.

### Problem

It all works fine until I implemented custom gestures on my main view using `Listener` and `GestureDetector` , where I guess the default `PageView` swipe gestures get overrode by those callback implementations.

### Expectation

Elsewhere with inheritance I could easily call super methods in my overrides, but with callbacks, I don't know where to derive the builtin behaviors.

### Question

What is the quickest way to incorporate the builtin page-navigation gestures into those custom gesture callbacks?

Comment: Did you try adding a ```pageController``` to the pageview and using the ```animateToPage``` method?

Comment: @Crazzygamerr Yes I have that controller. So you mean if I have access to that controller, I can call it from anywhere I want and make the switch?

Comment: If you have a controller, you can use it within the same class. Else ```InheritedWidget``` is the way to pass it to other classes.There you can use it normally. And don't forget to initialise the PageController of the InheritedWidget before using it in other classes

Comment: @Crazzygamerr Ok that's great. I wasn't sure if I could use it outside of its parent. In my case, it's a static member, so I don't even have to do the `InheritedWidget` dance and can call it elsewhere directly , right?

Comment: I'm pretty sure u can, but just make sure you don't use the pagecontroller before the widget is built.

Answer (score 0):

With @Crazzygamerr's tip, I managed to make it work.

Turns out that it is as simple as grabbing the `pageController` of the global `PageView` instance and `animateToPage` or `jumpToPage` as will.

You can do that from any class where you have access to the `pageController`.